# javascript chart library to show deviation in value

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I need a javascript charting library to draw a chart which shows deviation in value.some thing like this :

[image]

my ideal solution is filling areas marked with "up arrows" and "down arrows" with different color.I tried trending chart libraries but none of them worked.`high charts` , `charts js` , `chartist`,`eachart` ,... to name a few.

EDIT:

this is what i wan exactly:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [canvasJS](https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/custom-legend-chart/)??

I have included an example

```js
window.onload = function () {
 
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 //theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
 animationEnabled: true,
 title:{
  text: "Internet users"  
 },
 subtitles: [{
  text: "Try Clicking and Hovering over Legends!"
 }],
 axisX: {
  lineColor: "black",
  labelFontColor: "black"
 },
 axisY2: {
       gridThickness: 0,
  title: "% of Population",
  suffix: "%",
  titleFontColor: "black",
  labelFontColor: "black"
 },
 legend: {
  cursor: "pointer",
  itemmouseover: function(e) {
   e.dataSeries.lineThickness = e.chart.data[e.dataSeriesIndex].lineThickness * 2;
   e.dataSeries.markerSize = e.chart.data[e.dataSeriesIndex].markerSize + 2;
   e.chart.render();
  },
  itemmouseout: function(e) {
   e.dataSeries.lineThickness = e.chart.data[e.dataSeriesIndex].lineThickness / 2;
   e.dataSeries.markerSize = e.chart.data[e.dataSeriesIndex].markerSize - 2;
   e.chart.render();
  },
  itemclick: function (e) {
   if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
   } else {
    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
   }
   e.chart.render();
  }
 },
 toolTip: {
  shared: true
 },
 data: [{
  type: "spline",
  name: "Sweden",
  markerSize: 5,
       axisYType: "secondary",
  xValueFormatString: "YYYY",
  yValueFormatString: "#,##0.0\"%\"",
  showInLegend: true,
  dataPoints: [
   { x: new Date(2000, 00), y: 47.5 },
   { x: new Date(2005, 00), y: 64.8 },
   { x: new Date(2009, 00), y: 91 },
   { x: new Date(2010, 00), y: 50 },
   { x: new Date(2011, 00), y: 82.8 },
   { x: new Date(2012, 00), y: 93.2 },
   { x: new Date(2013, 00), y: 94.8 },
   { x: new Date(2014, 00), y: 92.5 }
  ]
 },
 {
  type: "spline",
  name: "UK",
  markerSize: 5,
  axisYType: "secondary",
  xValueFormatString: "YYYY",
  yValueFormatString: "#,##0.0\"%\"",
  showInLegend: true,
  dataPoints: [
   { x: new Date(2000, 00), y: 26.8 },
   { x: new Date(2005, 00), y: 70 },
   { x: new Date(2009, 00), y: 83.6 },
   { x: new Date(2010, 00), y: 85 },
   { x: new Date(2011, 00), y: 85.4 },
   { x: new Date(2012, 00), y: 87.5 },
   { x: new Date(2013, 00), y: 89.8 },
   { x: new Date(2014, 00), y: 91.6 }
  ]
 }]
});
chart.render();

}
```

```html
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but i am not able to see any intersection between two chart.

Comment: you have to alter the values. I have updated the chart

Comment: i've updated the answer.check that out.